# Is there any Stack Exchange that lets you ask alternate scenario questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

So my question is there any Stack Exchange site which was created to answer alternate scenario questions. I have tried googling it, but it instead gave me possible alternate scenarios of this particular website. For example, I have this question: If D-Day never happened, how would have Western Europe fared (also assuming that Marshall Plan never happened)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternate-history and alternate-reality questions are on-topic on [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), but you need to make sure they're not too broad and open-ended.  "What would happen if X event {happened, didn't happen}" is too open.  Instead, describe your context a little more and ask a more-specific question, along the following lines (I'm making up context here):

> In my alternate history, events up to the beginning of WW2 were the same but, because of [some reason you state here], the Allies never landed at Normandy and D-Day didn't happen.  The war [ended in some way that I will describe] instead.  What are the likely [economic, *or* military, *or* refugee-settlement, *or* ..., but not several] effects of this change on Western Europe over the next decade?

See also: [Worldbuilding on-topic help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: that was just an example. My real question is this one: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/65389/how-would-the-world-change-if-the-byzantine-empire-survived-till-the-modern-day#.